# How to create a action to a button in Cocoa programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, button, action

I'm trying to create a button in Cocoa in mac programmatically, but I don't know how to put a action on this, I'm trying like this:

```
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(10, 200, 80, 100);
NSButton *btn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
[btn setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
[btn setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
[btn setTitle:@"Click me"];
[btn setAction:@selector(hideLabels:)];

[view addSubview:btn];
```

but the line [btn setAction:@selector(hideLabels:)]; don't work, how can I create a action here?

the method hideLabels is in function, because I used it with another button.

Comment: what do you mean by "don't work"? Place an `NSLog` in `hideLabels` and see if anything prints out in Console.

Comment: You'll also need `[btn setTarget:self]`...

Comment: Thanks Matt Wilding, I put [btn setTarget:self]; before the action and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Does your hideLabels method take an argument?
if not, leave off the : from the selector

Comment: it Takes a sender argument, but I have other method hideNames with no arguments, this doesn't work too.